# c# create thead and tbody

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-applications, html-table

Can anyone tell me how to dynamically create thead tbody tags in my c# code?

```
private void MakeTable()
{
    Table tb = new Table();
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell td = new TableCell();
    td.Text="hello world";
    tr.Cells.Add(td);
    tb.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Somehow I read that as "thread" and it made absolutely no sense. Sorry for the interruption.

Comment: Same! (15 annoying characters to take up space)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here a sample code that creates a THead, TBody and TFooter.

You can basically always use the TableRow object just reset the TableSection property.

```
    Table table = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table();
    TableRow tableRow;
    TableCell tableCell;

    tableRow = new TableRow();
    tableRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    tableCell = new TableCell();
    tableCell.Text = "HEADER";
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
    table.Rows.Add(tableRow);

    tableRow = new TableRow();
    tableRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
    tableCell = new TableCell();
    tableCell.Text = "BODY";
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
    table.Rows.Add(tableRow);

    tableRow = new TableRow();
    tableRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
    tableCell = new TableCell();
    tableCell.Text = "FOOTER";
    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
    table.Rows.Add(tableRow);

    plhTest.Controls.Add(table);
```

Although I would suggest building the table in direct html and appending to page.

Comment: Any specific reasons why you would suggest that ("building the table in direct html and appending to page") ?

Comment: If you have to generate this dynamically (say, for unknown # of columns or other reasons) I found that the TableHeader will not render as `thead` UNLESS the TableFooter has been added (the footer can have no cells, but it must be added to the row collection). grrrr.

Comment: Be careful to add the TableHeaderRow via the Rows property of the table and NOT the controls property. Adding via the Controls property will _sometimes_ mean the thead element is not rendered to html.

Answer (score 7):

TableRow is basically `tbody`.

To make a `thead` section, use the [TableHeaderRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheaderrow.aspx) class instead of a TableRow class.

(There is also, btw, [TableFooterRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablefooterrow.aspx) if you want to implement `tfoot`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = new TableHeaderRow() { TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader };
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

should do the trick